# How can I automate php code validation on SVN setup?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I heard seen and experience it before where in my code was being rejected when I commit it on our SVN repository because there SVN Repository was configured to validate php code first and give the line error to you on Tortoise GUI as the reason why it cannot be committed.

So can anyone help how do I setup SVN like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the details, but generally it's done using **hooks**, which can be either server-side or client-side. The following links can help you find what you're looking for:

- http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html
- http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository-hooks.html

Comment: Thanks this was a great help but i think will try the one with the client / workstation side.. bcoz i dont have access to server yet :)

Comment: Client-side hooks are specific to each user's workstation. You cannot rely upon them for controlling/monitoring what lands in the repository.

Comment: oh yes yes i know.. thanks for the info but i just needed it for myself.. when im in a team that is isnt really teamly.. if you know what you i mean i only have to think of myself and my codes... in my case i cant choose who i want to work with i just stay silent and let them be ^__________^.. still i love my job